# SQL / Laravel: Is it possible to return a deduped results based on two column values?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have a fairly standard Chat model, which contains messages. For simplicity sake, let's say it has three columns: `to_user_id`, `from_user_id` and `message`.

I want to return a deduped results based on the two column values: `to_user_id` and `from_user_id`. This is a some I can list the ongoing conversations. I can return a return a deduped set of results using one column value. However, this essential comes back like the below. Obviously, this is because the user can be both the `to_user_id` and `from_user_id` depending on whether they sent or received the message.

Tom    >    Harry
Harry  >    Tom
John   >    Chris
Chris  >    John

I am hoping to get is something like the below, so it groupBy

Tom    >    Harry
John   >    Chris

Conversations are one-to-one, so will only ever have two participants.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id,to_user_id ,from_user_id) as source,  
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id,from_user_id,to_user_id ) as target 
FROM conversations;
```

Probably not suitable to be part of anything more complex.

Comment: Thanks for this - it really helpful! In your opinion, what would be the best way to pull through user information alongside the source / target IDs?

Comment: @TimRooke that's a bit outside by level of confidence with MySQL. I'd think you need to do something like `SELECT u1.*, u2.* FROM users u1 JOIN <this select> as alias ON u1.id=alias.source JOIN users u2 ON u2.id=alias.target` or something like that but not 100% sure

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. Not to worry, thanks anyway - I can work with what you've provided. Thanks!

Comment: in case you're interested managed to get this working - posted in the answers below.

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution,  but I suppose it should work. So idea in sort by user_id, so you will get unique pairs of conversation.

```
Select if(to_user_id > from_user_id, concat(from_user_id, ':', to_user_id), concat(to_user_id, ':', from_user_id)) as pair from messages group by pair;
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to join this up with data from the `users` table with the below solution. Thought I would share.

```
Select O.Sender, S.First_Name, S.Last_Name, O.Target, T.First_Name, 
T.LastName
From (
SELECT DISTINCT
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id, to_user_id, from_user_id) as sender,
    if(to_user_id > from_user_id, from_user_id, to_user_id ) as target 
FROM chats AS pair
) O
LEFT JOIN Users S ON O.Sender = S.UserID
LEFT JOIN Users T ON O.Target = T.UserID
```